# Is it possible to move a TFS repository from SQL 2012 Express to SQL 2008R2?

Tags: tfs

Does anybody know if it's possible to move a TFS repository from SQL 2012 Express to SQL 2008R2?

Background: 
At some point someone in our shop installed TFS to test it. This was done on a SQL 2012 Express. 
Over time this installation has become our de facto source control system and contains history for 25+ different solutions.

Now our Sys Admin would really like to get rid of this 2012 Express edition. Which means we have to move it to our 2008R2 SQL production server.

Comment: On a side note: why move away from SQL Express at all? Are you reaching the upper data limit?

Comment: No... The only reason is that our Sys admin likes to keep our system as clean as possible. And I totally agree with him :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know this is not officialy supported. SQL Server is backward compatible meaning you can go from 2008 to 2012. The other way around however is not supported.

By far the easiest solution would be to move to a regular SQL Server 2012 install. When you have a license for TFS, you also get a license for SQL Server Standard that you can use.

If that's not possible, you should contact Microsoft support. They have a script that you can use to migrate the data from one database to another. This can be done to run a downgrade but it's only supported if Microsoft helps you with it.

Comment: Thx for your input. We are currently running 2008R2 because a lot of our business is depending on a 3rd party tool. And the version we are using, isn't guaranteed to work with 2012. But we might upgrade soon. So that will help the situation. I was just asked to look at it our options right now. But it seems the easiest solution is to wait it out.